# Can I globally override semantic colors in my app?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, visionos

I was watching the visionOS presentation around UIKit, and they strongly recommended we should use semantic colors so the vibrancy would work properly.

However, I never found a proper way to override a palette of colors except for setting them at the root of the application's SwiftUI hierarchy through intermediate functions like `.foregroundColor(.mint)`.

However I don't seem to be able to control all colors used this way. Also, in UIKit, using a `UIAppearance` proxy is pretty laborious since you have to address all types of views separately.

Is there any way to simply override the palette itself instead of using indirect styling?

Comment: No, there is no simple solution

Answer (score 1):

If you build your own color library/design system, then you can define your own semantic colors, in the trade dress of your app. And then be rigorous about using, say, `MyCompany.bgPrimary` throughout. It's a bit painful to convert the first time, but you'll then have complete control over your palette, each color defined in exactly one place.

Comment: Thanks Hal, the reason I want to be able to control the semantic colors is because they are applied by default to many controls without me specifying them manually. What triggered me to ask this question is that in Vision Pro semantic colors have special properties in terms of vibrancy of backgrounds of floating apps.